# Swift 2d Array acts differently each run

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I am trying to populate a two dimensional array with a custom class called "card". I run it through two for loops to make a new "card" object and append it to the array. Every time I run the code block, I get differing amounts of objects ranging from 0 to millions.

```
    class arcade: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    createBoard()
    displayBoard()
}

func createBoard()
{
    var repCard = card()
    var board = [[card](count: 0, repeatedValue: repCard)]


    var indexCounter = 0;


    for var xInFor = 0; xInFor < 5; xInFor++ {

        for var yInFor = 0; yInFor < 5; yInFor++ {

            var newCard = card()
            newCard.width = 15.0
            newCard.id = indexCounter
            ++indexCounter
            var xPos = 50
            var yPos = 50

            newCard.x = xPos * xInFor
            newCard.y = yPos * yInFor

            board[xInFor].append(newCard)
        }
        board.append([card](count: 0, repeatedValue: repCard))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - I needed to declare my "board" array in the class not in the method